# Creating a framework with xib files inside

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to create a library/framework with xib files inside it ?

Same as MessageUI framework.
Need some reference examples.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried to do it both with libraries and frameworks ? And you seem to already have a reference example, please don't ask for step-by-step instructions but instead ask for help at specific steps that you are doing.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I have done without xib files but I was thinking about including xibs and not able to figure it how to implement.

Comment: Ok, `.xib` files are the same as any other files, the libraries do not carry resources but have you tried to create a simple framework, add some resources, build framework and check where the resources appear ? And what about resource bundles, did you try to create one for your library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to include xibs inside a static library/framework. You should create a bundle target that will contain all the xibs, image assets, etc that the library will need. In your library, you must then reference the resources from this bundle.